# Is it possible to install a standalone version of Detexify?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I think that when writing math [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a very nice tool --- verging on the indispensable.

When I am at home or in the office it is quite handy to use (the [android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coolcherrytrees.software.detexify&hl=en) would be great, unfortunately it's not working anymore); but if I am not connected (say, abroad or on a plane) it is obviously not working.

Is there any standalone version that I can install locally? (I use Linux, but probably can use other versions too).

Comment: The code for `detexify` is on GitHub: https://github.com/kirel/detexify and https://github.com/kirel/detexify-hs-backend

Comment: There is now a survey on http://detexify.kirelabs.org/ gauging interest for native & offline version.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin done thanks! I think that having a standalone app on my phone would be really the non-plus-ultra... rapidly sketching with the finger the symbol and voilà...

Comment: maybe one could write an electron wrapper to detexify if the 'standalone without internet' restriction is dropped

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, as the Haskell code is on GitHub:

- https://github.com/kirel/detexify Front-End
- https://github.com/kirel/detexify-hs-backend Back-End
- https://github.com/kirel/detexify-data Training data

However, it is not straight-forward to do so as some of the packages have changed. Additionally, it seems to me that setting a local Haskell server up is not very common.

Alternatively, you can use my project [`hwrt`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt). It should be relatively straight-forward to install. See http://pythonhosted.org/hwrt/installation.html to install it locally. It is completely ready packaged for offline usage (as a Python Flask webserver).

If you have problems with the installation you can leave a comment or send an email to me (info@martin-thoma.de).

Comment: I can't find where `pfile_utils` are ... and without them the last step fails (`hdf5.h: No such file or directory`). Any hints?

Comment: Marked as answered because it is, although I couldn't install it... Will try again after Christmas break. Thanks.

Comment: @Rmano: You don't need the `pfile_utils` as a normal user. They are only important for developers. Could you please try if installing `libhdf5-dev` fixes the problem?